# October CMS blog plugin | How can I preview blog post?

Tags: octobercms

Rainlab blog plugin provides some kind of preview with BlogMarkdown WYSIWYG editor although it's not what I've been expected from preview. But the client don't get the point of blogmarkdown (as well as I don't), so I changed it with default richtexteditor as it was explained [here](https://github.com/rainlab/blog-plugin/issues/112).
The obvious way is to publish post to look at it, but it's not a PREview, also I'm going to implement some kind of premoderation.
So, how can I take a look at post before publishing?

Comment: check this once - https://octobercms.com/plugin/radiantweb-problog

Answer (score 0):

A Page Preview plugin was recently published on the marketplace: https://octobercms.com/plugin/frozendo-pagepreview

Perhaps you could contact this author to look at creating one for the blog plugin also. Or you could fork it and do it yourself. The mechanics should be similar.